# Building count dictionary from statistics file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a statistics file like this:

`dict-count.txt`

```
apple   15
orange  12
mango   10
apple   1
banana  14
mango   4
```

I need to count the number of each element and create a dictionary like this: `{'orange': 12, 'mango': 14, 'apple': 16, 'banana': 14}`. I do the following to achieve this:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

with open('dict-count.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

output = {}

for line in lines:
    key, val = line.split('\t')
    output[key] = output.get(key, 0) + int(val)

print output
```

I am particularly concerned about this part:

```
key, val = line.split('\t')
output[key] = output.get(key, 0) + int(val)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or this is the only way?

Thanks.

Comment: You should remove the `lines = f.readlines()` and just iterate through f like `for line in f` inside the `with statement`

Comment: @jamylak: or he could put the `for` block inside the with block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a small file, you can use `.readlines()`, but that will slurp the entire contents of the file into memory in one go.  You can write this using the file object `f` as an iterator; when you iterate it, you get one line of input at a time.

So, the easiest way to write this is to use a `defaultdict` as @Amber already showed, but my version doesn't build a list of input lines; it just builds the dictionary as it goes.

I used terse variable names, like `d` for the dict instead of `output`.

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

d = defaultdict(int)

with open('dict-count.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.split()
        d[k] += int(v)

lst = d.items()

# sort twice: once for alphabetical order, then for frequency (descending).
# Because the Python sort is "stable", we will end up with descending
# frequency, but alphabetical order for any frequency values that are equal.
lst.sort(key=itemgetter(0))
lst.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

for key, value in lst:
    print("%10s| %d" % (key, value))
```

Comment: Thanks. But why do I get the output as `defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'orange': 12, 'mango': 14, 'apple': 16, 'banana': 14})`?

Comment: That's just what a `defaultdict` prints by default.  And dictionaries print their values in random order... You can easily make the output however you want with a loop; I'll modify the answer to print things in sorted order.

Comment: Thanks. I know the behavior of a `dict`. But the `defaultdict` seem to print a tuple `(type, dict)`. I am just wondering how to get just the `dict` part.

Comment: Here's an improved version that nicely sorts the output and prints in a nice format.

Comment: And here's a tricky way to do what you just asked:  `print dict.__repr__(d)`  We use the `.__repr__()` method function from the `dict` class explicitly rather than getting the one from the `defaultdict` class implicitly when we do the print.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(int)

with open('dict-count.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val = line.split('\t')
        output[key] += int(val)

print output
```